# Chart.js Example Code not working

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

For some reason, I don't know. My Chart.js code is not working as it should as the docs say..

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script></head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Chart.js — Line Chart Demo</h2>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'apples',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 6, 3, 7],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)"
    }, {
      label: 'oranges',
      data: [2, 29, 5, 5, 2, 3, 10],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.6)"
    }]
  }
});
  </script>
</html>
```

I'm a total newbie with Chart.js, please help me!

Comment: We shouldn't need to read the docs to understand your question. Tell us what doesn't work exactly

Comment: The charts can't be displayed. I'm not familiar with the bundles that I have to include to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is different if you are using Chart.js v1 or v2.

You imported the v1 library using `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>`.

But you actually used the v2 syntax :

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        // ...
    }
});
```

---

To fix this, you can either :

- Change the syntax to the v1's :

  ```
  var myChart= new Chart(ctx).Line({
      labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
      datasets: [{
              // ...
          }]
      });
  ```
- (**I suggest this option**) Change your imported library to the latest one using :

  ```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

include bundle.min.js 
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>`
example with your code https://jsfiddle.net/sv4snt39/1/

Comment: The bundle library is not essential in this case since the OP is not working with time-type charts. The `Chart.min.js` is enough